# Nginx ssl_protocols change

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-10.04

I am using Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and tryng to change Nginx ssl_protocols to

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

I restarted nginx and php5-fpm.

When checking the enabled protocols on www.ssllabs.com, I still have TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 only.

I tried to also comment this ssl_protocols line or leave TLSv1.2 only, but it doesn't seems to change anything. The GeoTrust website shows the same thing.

Which service do I need to restart in addition in order to be able to change the ssl_protocols in Nginx?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason after a few hours of searching:

I have two different domains runing on nginx and one of those two (not the one I was trying to edit) had the default_server setting, so it was that one I had to edit.